# declarative alpha changer

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'd like to write a `QDeclarativeItem` `FadeEdges` that I instantiate from `QML`, such as in this example:

```
FadeEdges {
  Text {
    id: sometext
    text: "some text"
  }
}
```

After `sometext` repaints, I'd like to reduce the alphas (from fully opaque to transparent) of the pixels it painted at its edges. So its rendered edges will appear faded. My question is what mechanisms, if any, are available to make this change in child alpha values.

I've tried to install event filters and setting `setFiltersChildEvents()`. No `PaintEvent`s seem to be sent.

Comment: I think `QGraphicsEffect` provides the answer, but this is a very slow, I think. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not an exact answer to my own question but I suppose it will do for starters. Only the `QGraphicsEffect::draw` member function needs to be overridden (`margins_` is a `QMargins` member variable):

```
void FadeEdgesEffect::draw(QPainter* painter)
{
  QLinearGradient lg;

  lg.setColorAt(qreal(0), QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
  lg.setColorAt(qreal(1), QColor(0, 0, 0, 255));

  qreal const width(boundingRect().width());
  qreal const height(boundingRect().height());

  QPoint offset;

  QPixmap pixmap(sourcePixmap(Qt::LogicalCoordinates, &offset));

  {
    QPainter p(&pixmap);

    p.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn);

    if (margins_.left())
    {
      lg.setStart(qreal(0), qreal(0));
      lg.setFinalStop(margins_.left(), qreal(0));

      p.fillRect(QRectF(0, 0, margins_.left(), height), lg);
    }
    // else do nothing

    if (margins_.right())
    {
      lg.setStart(qreal(width), qreal(0));
      lg.setFinalStop(width - margins_.right(), qreal(0));

      p.fillRect(QRectF(width - margins_.right(),
        0, margins_.right(), height), lg);
    }
    // else do nothing

    if (margins_.bottom())
    {
      lg.setStart(qreal(0), height);
      lg.setFinalStop(qreal(0), height - margins_.top());

      p.fillRect(QRectF(0, height - margins_.bottom(),
        width, margins_.bottom()), lg);
    }
    // else do nothing

    if (margins_.top())
    {
      lg.setStart(qreal(0), qreal(0));
      lg.setFinalStop(0, margins_.top());

      p.fillRect(QRectF(0, 0, width, margins_.top()), lg);
    }
    // else do nothing
  }

  painter->drawPixmap(offset, pixmap);
}
```